# Extract field from Object without $project twice MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Well, maybe it's a simple question but I didn't find any satisfied answer in mongoDB documentation about aggregation framework.

If I do a lookup that results in a array of matching docs, how I project only a field of the last element?

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            .... some lookup pipeline ....,
            as: "matchedObjects"
        }
    },
    {
        // Here I get the last Object
        $project: {
            doc:  { $arrayElemAt: [ { $slice: ["$matchedObjects", -1 ] }, 0 ]}
        }
    },
    {      
        // extract what I want
        $project: {
            field:  "$doc.field"
        }
    }
])
```

Well, how I do this with only the first $project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) to capture last element in temporary variable and then reference that variable to get `field`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            field: {
                $let: {
                    vars: { doc:  { $arrayElemAt: [ { $slice: ["$matchedObjects", -1 ] }, 0 ]} },
                    in: "$$doc.field"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. Didn't think of using $let this way